# ZF2 - Encoding label from form

Tags: encoding, zend-framework2

I've created a form using ZF2 when my whole system (page & server) is in french and has a ISO-8859-15 encoding. I don't have the power to change this encoding, so I guess we will have to deal with ANSI.

The issue is that when creating my form, I use this piece of code :

```
public function createAction() {
    BootstrapLogger::info(__METHOD__);
    $this->layout( 'layout/xhtml' );
    $dbAdapter = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');;
    $form = new ActionForm($dbAdapter);

    $form->get('submit')->setValue('Créer');

}
```

and get this error :

```
Message:
String to be escaped was not valid UTF-8 or could not be converted: Crï¿œer
```

I don't really understand why, nor how to avoid this.

As I'm guessing it's the same reason that, when creating my form, the labels are also wrongly encoded.

```
  $this->add( array(
            'name' => 'act_num',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => "N° action",
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'disabled' => 'disabled',
                'class' => 'form-control'
            )
        ));

    //ch2 - Libellé de l'action
    $this->add( array(
            'name' => 'act_label',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => "Libellé de l'action",
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'required' => 'required',
                'class' => 'form-control'
            )
        ));
```

This will give me

```
  Nï¿œ action
  Libellï¿œ de l'action
```

Same issue with the content of the select (that are populated by the SQLDb [that is in latin1_general_ci]).

Any idea how to fix this ?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying a different encoding for your form. Not sure how you use your InputFilter, because there are few different ways, but add this for every field.

```
'validators' => [
    [
        'name'    => 'StringLength',
        'options' => [
            'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
            'min' => 1,
        ],
    ],
],
```